# Where can I read/buy "Thunder Jet" manga?

Tags: resources, thunder-jet

Where can I find this manga: [Ginga Sengoku Gun Yuuden Rai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginga_Sengoku_Gun%27y%C5%ABden_Rai), also known as *The Heroes of Galaxy Wars* or *Thunder Jet*? I've been looking online for a place to buy this, but cannot seem to find it anywhere.

[image]

Comment: Google shopping has several of those for sale on eBay.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [the YesAsia website](http://www.yesasia.com/us/the-heroes-of-galaxy-wars-vol-27/1001825898-0-0-0-en/info.html).

It has several volumes of the manga you requested for sale for around $12 (€9). These releases are only in traditional Chinese and Japanese. As for English copies, I do not believe there are good sources to buy from as of now.